# The same MetaDescription with special chars from two ContentPages is being displayed differently in Google

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, meta-tags

I've run into an encoding problem with my ASP.Net 4.5 Web Application Project, Metadescriptions and Google.

I have two pages using the same MasterPage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="de" />
    <meta name="description" content="...für..." />
...
```

I have two ContentPages A and B that both use this MasterPage and do not change the MetaDescription.
However, in Google they won't show the same MetaDescription (Under each search result in Google is some text displayed, and for these two pages it's their MetaDescription).

**ContentPage A** shows "fÃ¼r" anstead of "für"
**ContentPage B** shows "für" correctly

I can't seem to find to find the big difference between these pages. They render different content from the database. I have this issue on about ~10% of my pages. A commonality that I've found is that every page displaying a News from my database shows the wrong encoding for the meta description. Other pages that include different content, may or may not have this problem, as well.
I guess Google 'incorrectly' assumes another enconding for the whole page?

How can I trace this properly?

Both headers from the contentpages look the same in the 'view source'-window in Chrome:

**Page A**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="de" />
<meta name="description" content="...für..." />
```

**Page B**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="de" />
<meta name="description" content="...für..." />
```

How can I get rid of that encoding issue and have the meta description show up correctly in a Googlesearch? Most of the other contentpages do not have any problems with encoding in a Googlesearch.

Answer (score 0):

This is long shot but considering that you are serving xhtml, try one or combinations of below things

1. Remove `xml:lang` from html tag
2. Try `xml:lang="de"`
3. Try adding xml declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>`

Comment: Ok, haven't thought of that, but that suggests that I have this problem on every contentpage, which I don't. I guess the problem is due to Google. I've also tried using Fiddler but I can't see any encoding difference in the meta description as well

Comment: @citronas, what I am simply saying that google probably assumes encoding to be different based on the actual content and it would be very difficult to figure out that. But at least, you can try giving google all standard hints about encoding so that it may use one of that!